# read table from subfolder of tar.gz file

Tags: r

table can open a file directly from tar.gz file

```
myData <- read.table('myFile.tar.gz')
```

However without having to unzip and then delete is there a way to read the table of a specific file in the compress file, so for example under firstf/secondf/table.txt?

there has been a similar post but note quite what I need. 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I found an answer by using a package call archive.

```
library ( archive ) 
file <- "test.tar.gz" 

x <- archive::archive_read(archive = file , file = "firstf/secondf/table.txt") 
df <- read.table(x, header=TRUE,sep="\t",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```